# Blowing up along the point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is quasi-projective variety, I want to prove that blow up along the point $p$ can be embedded to $\mathbb{P}^{n(n+1)-1}$.

I proved it like that:
$X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$. After projective change of coordinates, we can assume W.L.O.G $p=[0:\ldots:0:1]$. Then by definition, blow up of $X$ along the point $p$ is the graph of the rational map $\phi$, where $\phi : X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ such that $[x_0:x_1:\ldots:x_{n-1}:x_n] \longmapsto [x_0:x_1:\ldots:x_{n-1}]$. By using Segre embedding, we find that $X\times\mathbb{P}^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n(n+1)-1}$. $B_p(X)$ is the closed subset of $X\times\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, hence according to the abovementioned inclusion it can be embedded to $\mathbb{P}^{n(n+1)-1}$ (it is enough to take the restriction of Segre embedding $\sum_{n, {n-1}}$ to  $B_p(X)$).
Can anyone help me is it true? Or I am missing something important in the proof.

Comment: This is fine. ${}$